# Allocating and deallocating memory using free() inside a function in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I am just unable to figure out how to release the memory I have allocated inside a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node node_t;

struct node {
    int data;
    node_t* next;
};

void insert(node_t** head, int data) {

    node_t* temp = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    node_t* ptr;

    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = temp;
    } else {
        ptr = *head;

        while(ptr->next != NULL) {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = temp;
    }

}

node_t* arrayToLL(int *arr, int size) {
    node_t* head = NULL;

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        insert(&head, arr[i]);
    }

    return head;
}

void printList(struct node* head) {
    while (head->next!=NULL) {
        printf("%d -> ", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("%d\n", head->data);
}


int main() {

    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    node_t* head = NULL;

    head = arrayToLL(arr, size);

    printList(head);

    free(head);
    head = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

If I run it with `gcc main.c -fsanitize=address -o main && ./main` then it warns me about memory leaks like below,

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

=================================================================
==775653==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f675ceb4867 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
    #1 0x55b502d672c5 in insert (/home/altair/linkedlist/main+0x12c5)
    #2 0x55b502d6753a in arrayToLL (/home/altair/linkedlist/main+0x153a)
    #3 0x55b502d67887 in main (/home/altair/linkedlist/main+0x1887)
    #4 0x7f675ca29d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f)

Indirect leak of 48 byte(s) in 3 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f675ceb4867 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
    #1 0x55b502d672c5 in insert (/home/altair/linkedlist/main+0x12c5)
    #2 0x55b502d6753a in arrayToLL (/home/altair/linkedlist/main+0x153a)
    #3 0x55b502d67887 in main (/home/altair/linkedlist/main+0x1887)
    #4 0x7f675ca29d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 64 byte(s) leaked in 4 allocation(s).
```

I know that the head pointer I have allocated inside `arrayToLL(int *arr, int size)` can be released by `free(head)` from the main function. But what about the `*temp` and `*ptr` inside `insert(node_t** head, int data)`. And I am guessing these not released allocated memory is causing the memory leaks.

My question is how to free the pointer memory I have allocated inside a void function or at least how to avoid those memory leaks?

Comment: You have size (4) malloc and only one free! You need as many free as you inserted element.

Comment: `free(head)` frees *one* node; not the entire list. You free the list by enumeration, similar (but not identical) to enumeration done for printing. Paper + boxes + arrows assist greatly in working that algorithm. `while (head) { void *ptr=head; head = head->next; free(ptr); }` is literally the entire algorithm.

Comment: @WhozCraig this is the solution I was looking for actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that the head pointer I have allocated inside `arrayToLL(int *arr, int size)` can be released by `free(head)` from the main function.

In your program, all dynamic memory allocation occurs in `arrayToLL()`, but none occurs *directly* in that function.  Only function `insert()` calls `malloc()` directly.

> But what about the `*temp` and `*ptr` inside `insert(node_t** head, int data)`.

It is not about the variables that store pointers to the allocated space, as you should already know based on your remarks about `head`.  It is about pointer *values*, whatever variable they happen to be stored in (if any).

So where do the pointers to the allocated storage spaces go?  If the list is initially empty, `insert()` feeds the pointer value back to its caller via its out argument, `head` (which is a separate variable from the like-named ones in other functions).  If the list is *not* initially empty, then the pointer value ends up stored in the `next` member of one of the nodes.

To free the allocated memory, then, you need to walk the list and free each node, being careful to avoid freeing any given node before reading out its `next` pointer so as to know what node to free next.